# How do I turn a table of contents into plain formatted text?

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, table-of-contents, field-codes, microsoft-word-2011

How do I turn a table of contents into a plain formatted text without field codes? I want to cut it away from the rest of the doc as an outline.

I'm using Word 2011 on a Mac.

Answer (score 9):

The Table of Contents is a fieldcode so it can be converted to text by unlinking the fieldcode.

Do the following:

1. Highlight the entire Table of Contents.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (Windows) or or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (Mac) to unlink the field code.

Comment: @Kirstin, you should mark this as answer to help the community in knowing this works appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same format and remove that annoying frame around the TOC after you made it static try this:

1. Select the text of TOC.
2. Copy and Paste to a new location using "Use destination styles (S)" mode]
3. Uncheck "Keep Content Controls" box
4. Enjoy!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Simple Solution:` Merge the cells and copy the content inside.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Select the text inside the table of contents.

> [image]

Then, click *Edit » Copy* (or `Cmd-C`) and click *Edit » Paste Special…* (or `Cmd-Ctrl-V`). Here, select the option to paste as "Unformatted Text". This is the result – apply formatting as you wish:

> [image]

If you want to keep the style, paste as "Styled Text":

> [image]

Comment: it doesn't give a "paste as styled text" option

Comment: I'm using Word 2011 too, on OS X. It's [right there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw2f6.png). What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the formatting as it looks in your original document, you can take a screen shot of the pages and save it as an image, then print that.

Another way to keep the formatting, is paste as stylized text then manually put in full stops.